# Defining user and team billing plans in Laravel Spark - however not seeing team plans in register page

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm trying to get my head around Laravel Spark's billing plans - and specifically using both the individual and team plans in the same application.

The billing documentation specifically states you can define user and team billing within the same application.

However, if an individual "user plan" is in place, the system doesn't seem to ever show the "team plans" on the registration form.

I've been through the documentation and search for various solutions however, unless I'm missing the obvious, can't see anyone else commenting on this.

```
    Spark::plan('Individual', 'ind_plan')
        ->price(10)
->features([
            'First', 'Second', 'Third'
        ]);


Spark::teamPlan('Team', 'team_plan')
    ->price(10)
    ->features([
        'Feature 1',
        'Feature 2',
        'Feature 3',
    ]);
```

I was expecting to see on the registration form both plans; and if the team plan was chosen, for it to ask me the team name.

However, it just shows the individual plan.

Yet if I change the "teamPlan" to "plan" and refresh, both are shown.

Has anyone seen this before?

And any idea how to get both to show... or what I'm missing?

The system was installed with the latest version using *spark new project* --team-billing

Thank you.

Comment: There's likely a configuration option that was missed along the way. It's also possible that the initial spark install was for individual plans only.

Comment: Hi Marcel, thank you for your reply.

The system was installed using _spark new project --team-billing_

And if I just have _plans_ it works as you'd expect and the same if you have _teamPlans_.  But not both?

cheers,

Comment: In order to show both types of plans, you may need to modify the views to include loops to display both plan types: `$sparkPlans = Spark::plans();` and  `Spark::teamPlans()`